# How to change the pip version in pycharm

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

In pycharm the pip version is showing as 10.1 but when i check the pip version in my CMD it is showing as 9.0.1.

I am not able to understand why it is happening.

If any one know the reason can you please let me know and also tell let me know how to use pip 9.0.1 in my pycharm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of the fact that pycharm and the system are using two different python virtual environments.

You can fix it from 2 ends, either from pycharm or from the system version: depending on whichever is favorable for you.

From Pycharm, follow the below steps:

1. Open project settings (File > Settings...) (preferences on Mac)
2. Type pip in the search bar.
3. Select the pip in the right search results.
4. Select the checkbox 'specify version' and select the required version.

Attached screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response it worked for me

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Visit this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elbHf9sAy-0 it may help!
Good luck!

Comment: Can you summarize what the video says? Just posting links isn't as useful. See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer section "Provide context for links"